# How to append a single element to a list keyed in a dict

Tags: kdb, q-lang

If I have

```
dict:`a`b!(1 2 3;4 5 6 7)
```

Can I append an element to dict`b without redeclaring the whole dict?

ie what's the best way to get to

```
dict:`a`b!(1 2 3;4 5 6 7 8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
dict[`b],:8
```

but it will automatically overwrite the dictionary.

A more robust way would be

```
@[dict;`b;,;8]
```

or

```
 @[`dict;`b;,;8]
```

where the latter automatically overwrites the dictionary, while the former creates a modified copy of the dictionary (in case you don't want it to overwrite the original yet)